# Using bracket notation with a variable to access object property returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm relatively new to TypeScript and I'm confused about why using bracket notation on an object with variable as a key always returns `undefined`. I have an object defined that looks something like,

```
{
    "data": {
        "text": "hello"
    } 
}
```

that I import into my code using something like `import * as myBlob from ./data.json`. When I access the the `data` key of `myBlob` using the bracket notation with a string literal as key (`myBlob['data']`), it works as expected. However, this access pattern returns `undefined`:

```
let key = 'data';
myBlob[key]; //undefined
```

I hope someone can enlighten me on why this is happening.

Comment: It's not clear if you're actually using that syntax to import the JSON or not ("something like" is vague), but if you're using that exact syntax then it shouldn't be async, so you shouldn't be having async issues. If you're actually using a different manner for importing the JSON (e.g., `fetch` or XHR), then you need to wait until it's been retrieved before accessing the data.

Comment: That's the import pattern I'm using. I only said "something like" because that's not what's exactly in my code.

Comment: I would debug then. Set a breakpoint on the line and inspect the `myBlob` variable and see what's in it at the time you're trying to access it.

Comment: why do you use `* as` ?

Comment: maybe myBlob is a string not js object

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

`import * as importedMyBlob from ./data.json`

Then use it like the following:

`const myBlob = importedMyBlob.default;`